# Swift: I get Debugging "errors" when I try to make my program work

Tags: swift

I followed an online tutorial on youtube for a Hello World like program for Swift.  Even though I typed the code just like the code in the tutorial it till gives me a debugging error (the green errors). I researched problems like this but the code was to complicated and was over my head.  Usually I code in java, but I have been wanting to develop for mobile.  Anyways, if you can tell me:
1. What the error means.
2. How I can fix it.
3. How can I prevent errors like this.

NameLabel.text = "Hi (nameTextField.text)"    is the line I get the error on.
Here is my code:

```
  import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var NameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func HelloWorldAction(nameTextField: UITextField) {
    NameLabel.text = "Hi \(nameTextField.text)"
}
```

}

Comment: How are you calling the HelloWorldAction function? It looks weird trying to pass the TextField as a parameter of the function. It would be easier if the TextField was another IBoutlet so that you could get the value afterwards. (I.E.: a button press calls the action and you get the String from your TextField).

Comment: Post the debugger output.

Answer (score 0):

nameTextField is't @IBAction. It's @IBOutlet. 
I made a button and it appropriated action. I have everything working.

```
  @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton!) {
   NameLabel.text = "Hi \(namedTextField.text)"
  }
```